# How to change relations on extended data types imported from AX 2009 to table references?

Tags: migration, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have some extended data types imported from AX 2009 to AX 2012. (They was created by someone else than me and imported by someone else.) They have relations on them but it should be ok because they are related to 1 table. They can be recreated in AX 2012 way using table reference.

But there are some problems in my way to recreate them in AX 2012 way.

1) The table relation can not be set. (Probably because there is relation on EDT).

2) I can not find how to delete whole relation group.

3) When I try to delete relation from relation group my AX client stop working.

Is there some way how to recreate EDT migrated from AX 2009 to AX 2012. (I want to keep the names due to the existence EDT on tables, return types in methods etc.)

I try to use EDT migration tool but it tells me that I will need to migrate the EDT manually (or skip migration at all).

Could anyone give me some trick how to migrate relations on EDT (related to single table) to the table references with keep of the EDT on tables, return types in methods etc. (Without destroying tables etc.)?

(Some trick with import/export.)

Comment: What do you mean by "relation group"? A relation node under a table?

Comment: "Relations" node under extended data type. (The EDT created in AX2012 do not have it but some of old ones imported from AX2009 has it.)

Comment: You do not need to delete it, you can mark your fields to ignore EDT relations.

Comment: Try to compare the export of a new and old type EDT.

Comment: ... And don't forget the 'Migrating Extended Data Type Relations (White paper)' by Microsoft! http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272870.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created them all again, export tables to .xpo and replace old ones by new ones.